# Cowrie (Honeypot) to not store passwords for certain username entries

Tags: linux, security, centos, honeypot

I need certain usernames to be logged without passwords. So if someone logs in with the username "jack" and the password "passw0rd", it will only not log the password while if someone were to login with "harvey" and the password "password" it will log the harvey's username and password.

```
Server (please complete the following information):

OS: NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

Python:
Python 2.7.5
```

Comment: You might get lucky and get your question answered, but feel free to post it here too: https://security.stackexchange.com/